# Appropriate time to use complex css selector

Tags: css

I found myself never use advance selector like x + y, x > y, x~y etc because I've no idea when to use it. It make my developement slower if I would like to implement those because I'm no good in making shortcut.

eg. why use x + y in a list instead x y ? or directly select the id or class.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#combinators

Comment: And you don't have to use them if you're uncomfortable with them.

Comment: This article might be helpful: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: `x + y` and `x y` are completely different selectors; the first selects the `y` element directly after `x`, and the second selects the `y` descendants of `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've no idea when to use it, don't. As a general rule of thumb, if it makes your development slower and you don't understand the purpose of it, don't do it. Specifically though:

```
x y
```

Means select any `y` nested within a `x`

```
x + y
```

Means select any `y` that comes immediately after an `x`

```
x > y
```

Means select any `y` that is an immediate child of `x`

```
x ~ y
```

Means select any `y` that comes after an `x`

Comment: I know the meaning of those. But when to use them? I don't seem prefer to use those..

Comment: You use them when these are the only ways of targeting `y`. If you don't need to, you don't need to! But sometimes the markup is inflexible and out of your control and these are the only ways of targeting the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

Those advanced selectors (x > y, x + y, x ~ y) are really useful in certain cases as they are more specific than just `x y`. Some examples:

1. x > y

   ```
   <ul class="nav">
       <li>
           One
           <ul>
               <li>Three</li>
               <li>Four</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <li>
           Two
           <ul>
               <li>Five</li>
               <li>Six</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```

   Imagine you want to have margin-bottom for top-level nav only. Quite a common situation. As simple as:

   ```
   .nav > li {margin-bottom: 10px}
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   .nav li {margin-bottom: 10px} .nav li li {margin-bottom: 0}
   ```
2. x + y

   ```
       <h1>Heading</h1>
       <p>First paragraph.</p>
       <p>Second paragraph.</p>
   ```

   For some stylistic reasons you want first paragraphs to have a different font-style. Simple, again:

   ```
   h1 + p {font-style: italic;}
   ```

To do that without adjacent selector ('+') you'd have to add a class to every first paragraph after headings, which may be tiring for a long article.